# how to make barcode work with device keys?

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to code an inventory app that can work on UROVO DT40 device. I don't know how to code the barcode scanner so that it will work on keystroke and send the result to edittext. I also want to save the data from the adapter and be able to read from a PC. I am still a rookie so I don't know if am doing it the right way. I need some help please. Thanks!!

here's some of the code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {ArrayList<String> 
listitems = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextInputEditText input = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText);
    TextInputEditText input1 = findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText1);

    ListView listview = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Button saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    Button btn_annuler = findViewById(R.id.btn_annuler);
    Button OK = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2) ;

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listitems);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    input.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
    input1.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

    OK.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        listitems.add(Objects.requireNonNull(input.getText()).toString() + ';' + Objects.requireNonNull(input1.getText()).toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        input.setText("");
        input1.setText("");
    });

    btn_annuler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            input.setText("");
            input1.setText("");
                        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.clear();
        }
    });

    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!adapter.toString().equals(""))
            {
                String data = adapter.toString();
                writeToFile(data);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vidage éffectué!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

}

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("ficGloba.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You mention that you want the Scanner to work upon keystroke yet this seems to be an Android App. To which key (or button) do you want to bind the Scanner?

Comment: Yes it's an Android App that will run on scanning device (UROVO DT40). the work flow is: when I press the scanning button on the device, the result appears in the input.

Answer (score 0):

There are code samples on the [Urovo github page](https://github.com/urovosamples) for the Android SDK, specifically also one for the [Scanner](https://github.com/urovosamples/SDK_ReleaseforAndroid/blob/master/Samples/ScanManager/app/src/main/java/com/scan/demo/ScanManagerDemo.java)

Steps 1 to 4 from from the ScannerManagerDemo.java javadoc describe how you have to setup the Scanner:

> - 1.Obtain an instance of BarCodeReader with ScanManager scan = new ScanManager().
> - 2.Call openScanner to power on the barcode reader.
> - 3.After that, the default output mode is TextBox Mode that send barcode data to the focused text box. User can check the output mode
>   using getOutputMode and set the output mode using switchOutputMode.
> - 4.Then, the default trigger mode is manually trigger signal. User can check the trigger mode using getTriggerMode and set the trigger mode
>   using setTriggerMode.

for full completeness, the extracted javacode:

```
private void initScan() {
        mScanManager = new ScanManager();
        boolean powerOn = mScanManager.getScannerState();
        if (!powerOn) {
            powerOn = mScanManager.openScanner();
            if (!powerOn) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Scanner cannot be turned on!");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog mAlertDialog = builder.create();
                mAlertDialog.show();
            }
        }
        initBarcodeParameters();
    }
```

That should give you enough to get cracking. Godspeed.